# c# Using an action from GUI while running thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

**Question :**

I'm a beginner in c# and i'm having a bit of trouble to understand how thread works with a form. I'm trying to update a progressbar when my program hit keypoints and i can't get it to work here is my code.

For my "worker" class :

```
public void addFollower(string followerName, Action<string> followerAction) {
        this.followers.Add(followerName, followerAction);
    }
private void notifyFollowers(string message) {
    if (followers.Count > 0) {
        foreach (String followerName in followers.Keys) {
            followers[followerName].Invoke(message); 
        }
    }
}
```

for my linking class (controller maybe?) :

```
public void runWithParams(Dictionary<string,string> parameters, Action<string> updateManager = null){
        string app = parameters["appName"];
        string navigator = parameters["navigatorName"];
        string mode = parameters["mode"];
        string scenario = parameters["scenarioName"];
        try {
            Scenario sc = this.scenarioBuilders[app].buildScenario(scenario);
            if(updateManager != null) sc.addFollower("updateManager", updateManager);
            Thread TestRunner = new Thread(sc.run);
            TestRunner.Start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Unexpected shutdown or driver unreachable");
        }
}
```

For the gui :

```
private void ButtonRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>{
            {"appName",this.CBApplicationChoice.SelectedItem.ToString()},
            {"navigatorName",this.CBNavigatorChoice.SelectedItem.ToString()},
            {"mode",this.CBModeChoice.SelectedItem.ToString()},
            {"scenarioName",this.CBScenarioChoice.SelectedItem.ToString()}
        };
        this.dispatcher.runWithParams(parameters, ManageRealTimeStep1);
    }

    public void ManageRealTimeStep1(string liveevent){
        if (liveevent.Contains("NumberOfPages")) {
            this.PBStep1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(liveevent.Split(':')[1]);
        } else if (liveevent.Contains("StartingTestNewPage")) {
            this.PBStep1.Increment(1);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an InvalidOperationException when i click on the RunButton and the error says that i'm trying to call a function that is in another thread. How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance for any answer/ insights

**Solution :**

I changed the method in gui for :

```
public void ManageRealTimeStep1(string liveevent) {
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
            if (liveevent.Contains("NumberOfPages")) {
                this.PBStep1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(liveevent.Split(':')[1]);
            } else if (liveevent.Contains("StartingTestNewPage")) {
                this.PBStep1.Increment(1);
            }
        }));
}
```

Comment: There's no actual question here.

Comment: Edited sorry i forgot to write it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BeginInvoke` method:

```
BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
   this.PBStep1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(liveevent.Split(':')[1]);
}));
```

Read more about updating WinForms UI from another thread [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10311/What-s-up-with-BeginInvoke)

Comment: Worker perfectly i'll edit my question with the solution and mark you as answer asap

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to update the GUI from a different thread, see [How to update the GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/661561).

You are accessing the GUI from the `ManageRealTimeStep1` method which is used by the `Scenario` class (as a callback) on the background thread.

Comment: using invoke and beginInvoke fixed my problem, is it considered bad practice?

Comment: Not bad practice - it's the only way to update the GUI from a separate thread. Technically, it is a design pattern.